# How to pass data and url from ajax to controller?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a product page, my galleries are a subcategory of products.

```
Route::resource('products.galleries', 'GalleryController');
```

How can I transfer both IDs to the controller?

- `product_id`
- `gallery_id`

ajax

```
@isset($gallery)
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{ route('products.galleries.destroy', [$product->id, $gajllery->id]) }}',
    data : {
        "_method" : "DELETE" ,
        name
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (e){
        console.log(e);
    },
});
@endisset
```

GalleryController.php

```
public function destroy(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $filename = $request->get('name');
    dd($filename);
    Gallery::where('image', $filename)->delete();
    Storage::disk('public')->delete($filename);
}
```

It does not even show us `dd($filename);`.

**Note**: This code has no errors at all.

Comment: There are 2 things - first there is spelling error in ajax call for `$gallery` variable, secondly there is no definition for `name` for ajax data. Because it is ajax you will not see the error in  page, it will be visible in the network response. Can you see if there is any error coming over there?

Comment: This code has no errors at all. I do not  see any an error.

Comment: Can you see any console errors. I believe your syntax could have cause js issue. `url: '{{ route('products.galleries.destroy', [$product->id, $gajllery->id]) }}'`. You are using nested single quotations `'`, which will not work properly. Try double quotes `"` and single quotes `'` to define the url.

Comment: Like this? `url: "{{ route('products.galleries.destroy', [$product->id, $gajllery->id]) }}",`

Comment: @ajayramgarhia I see this message in console https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnxXv.png

Comment: Can you make sure that ajax is running? As you have `isset` condition outside of `script` tag. So if `$gallery` variable is not set, then your script code is not present at all. If your ajax is working, can you see the response in chrome Network Response tab? Also which code is outputting the console output that you attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236221/discussion-between-developer-laravel-and-ajay-ramgarhia).

Comment: Have you anyDesk?

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel your problem has solved? If not then tell me I can helps to you

Comment: No, my problem hasn't been solved

Comment: Answer my question..